# ExportToPDF hangs in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, pdf, layouts

Several tools used throughout my organization use ArcPy's ExportToPDF method. A couple of weeks ago, when we upgraded from 2.7.x to 2.8.0, these tools stopped working (for myself and other users).

Regular .py scripts, .tbx files, and .pyt files are impacted.

Here is a code snippet that hangs without giving an error message (the wheel just keeps spinning):

```
import arcpy

aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
lyt = aprx.listLayouts("Layout")[0]

lyt.exportToPDF(r"\\myNetworkPath\testPDFsFolder\test123.pdf")
```

What is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Esri Staff in the following link, this is a known bug that is fixed with the 2.8.3 software update:

https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/exporttopdf-hangs-in-arcgis-pro-2-8-running-from/td-p/1062894

I have tested that upgrading does fix the problem, and ExportToPDF now works.

Edit: More info on the bug can be found [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/get-started/release-notes.htm) (see BUG-000140623).
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Interesting... I have 2.8.3 installed and was still experiencing this PDF export hang up with a complex layer in my layout.  I went in and found it had some Python and VBScript expressions in its many label classes.  I updated everything to Arcade, and the PDF hang up went away and it exported properly in ArcPy, so this bug may not be completely "cured".  I guess the takeaway here is to put all label expressions in Arcade if possible to avoid this bug completely.

Comment: The bug also appears to still be occurring in 2.9.5